# Using case and group-by at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case

I want to use `case` in SQL, but also using the right `group by`

```
SELECT patientname, patientid, cancerstatus,    
  CASE
    WHEN cancerstatus IS NOT NULL THEN 'In surgery'
    WHEN cancerstatus IS NULL THEN 'no surgery needed'        
  END case
FROM database (nolock)
WHERE biopsydate BETWEEN '2020-08-25' AND '2020-08-26'
GROUP BY patientname, patientID
```

So I want to a case expression to put every patient who had cancer biopsy in categories of needing surgery or not, and I also want to group patients using patientID and name (those two criteras are must have).

It's showing error around the `case` part, what did I do wrong?

Comment: You can probably put `'no surgery needed'` in the `ELSE` part of the `CASE` - you don't need to test for it since the first test is `is not null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to repeat the `case` in the `group by`, I think:

```
SELECT patientname, patientid,
       (CASE WHEN PJMPSID is not null, THEN 'In surgery'
             WHEN cancerstatus is null then 'no surgery needed'    
        END) as status
FROM database
WHERE biopsydate between '2020-08-25' and '2020-08-26'
GROUP BY patientname, patientID,
         (CASE WHEN PJMPSID is not null, THEN 'In surgery'
               WHEN cancerstatus is null then 'no surgery needed'    
          END);
```

Some notes:

- `NOLOCK` should not be used, unless you really know what you are doing.
- You are apparently using SQL Server.  You should tag the question.
- The `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` columns need to be consistent.  It doesn't make sense to include `cancerstatus` in the `SELECT`, unless it is also in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hey thanks, it's giving me an error on cancerstatus fielde, I updated the question. Because you are replacing the cancerstatus with a case, if I'm not mistaken?